# How to use grep to find a specific string of numbers and move that to a new test file

Tags: text, grep, find

I am new to using linux and grep and I am looking for some direction in how to use grep. I am trying to get two specific numbers from a text file. I will need to do this for thousands of files so I believe using grep or some equivalent to be best for my mental health.

The text file I am working with looks as follows:

```
*Average spectrum energy:    0.00100 MeV
 Average sampled energy :    0.00100 MeV [ -0.0000%]
 K/phi    = <E*mu_tr/rho>         = 6.529719E+02 10^-12 Gy cm^2 [ 0.0008%]
 Kcol/phi = <E*mu_tr/rho>*(1-<g>) = 6.529719E+02 10^-12 Gy cm^2 [ 0.0008%]
 <g>                              =   1.0000E-15 [  0.4264%]
 1-<g>                            =     1.000000 [  0.0000%]
<mu_tr/rho> = <E*mu_tr/rho>/Eave         = 4.075530E+03   cm^2/g [ 0.0008%]
<mu_en/rho> = <E*mu_tr/rho>*(1-<g>)/Eave = 4.075530E+03   cm^2/g [ 0.0008%]
<E*mu_en/rho>                            = 4.075530E+00   MeV cm^2/g
```

The values I am looking to extract from this are "0.00100" and "4.075530E+00".

At the moment I am using `grep -iE "Average spectrum energy|<E*mu_en/rho>"  *` which is allowing me to see the full lines, but I am not quite sure how to refine the search to only show me the numbers instead of just the whole line. Is this possible using grep?

As for moving the numbers into a new file, I believe the command is `> newdata.txt`. My question is when using this with grep can you change how it writes the data to the new text file? I am looking for the format of the numbers to be like this:

```
0.00100001    3.4877754595352117
0.00100367    3.4665273232204363
0.00100735    3.4453747056004884
0.00101104    3.4243696230289187
0.00101474    3.4035147003587718
```

Again is that possble using the grep `> newdata.txt`?

I really appreciate any help or direction people can give me. Thank you.

Comment: The command you say you're using doesn't yield the (last) line with _"4.075530E+00"_, but rather the (second-to-last) line with `4.075530E+03`. Which one do you really want?

Comment: HI, thank you for pointing that out. I missed it somehow. It is the 4.075530E+00 value that I am looking for, I'm not quite sure why it was giving the 4.075530E+03 value.

Comment: The numbers in the format you are _looking for_ have more significant digits than the shown input. You surely are aware that this is impossible.

Comment: I fully agree with you. Unfortunately I cannot change the output of the numbers in the program I am using to generate the data. I will need to think of a creative way to amend the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not quite sure why it was giving the 4.075530E+03 value.

That's because `*` has the special meaning of a repetition of the previous item any number of times (including zero), so the pattern `<E*mu_en/rho>` does not match the text `<E*mu_en/rho>`, but rather `<` any number of `E` `mu_en/rho>`, i. e. especially `<mu_en/rho>`. To escape this special meaning and match a literal `*`, prepend a backslash, i. e. `<E\*mu_en/rho>`.

> I am not quite sure how to refine the search to only show me the numbers instead of just the whole line. Is this possible using grep?

It is if PCRE (`grep -P`) is available in the system. To only (`-o`) show the numbers, we can use the feature of [Resetting the match start](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#resetmatchstart) with `\K`. Your modified `grep` command is then:

```
grep -hioP "(Average spectrum energy: *|<E\*mu_en/rho> *= )\K\S*" *
```

(option `-h` drops the file names, pattern item `\S` means *not a white space*).

> when using this with grep can you change how it writes the data to the new text file?

`grep` by itself cannot change the format of numbers (except maybe cutting digits off). If you want this, we need another tool. Now, since we need another tool, I'd consider using a tool which is capable of doing the whole job, e. g. `awk`:

```
awk '
/Average spectrum energy/ { printf "%.8f    ", $4 }
/<E\*mu_en\/rho>/         { printf "%.16f\n", $3 }
' * >newdata.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the help. I understand what you mean about grep not being able to change format by itself, so thank you for introducing me to awk. I tried the example awk command line, but I am given the following error "awk: read error (Is a directory)". I have checked and I don't have a directory called awk so I don't really understand why it is giving this error. Is there any resources you would recommend about awk so I could read up on its use? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry, forget my last comment. I was able to get it working using the awk command you provided. I just needed to move the files to a different folder to get it to work. Below is how it outputs the data.    0.00100000    4.0755299999999997
0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000
0.00100000    4.0522260000000001
0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000
0.00101000    4.0290549999999996
0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000
0.00101000    4.0060159999999998
0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000  I don't know why it's giving the two lines of zero values though.

Comment: Regarding the _lines of zero values_, I can think of two possible reasons: a) There are other files with lines containing `<E*mu_en/rho>`. (By the way, how are your text files named?) b) There are other lines containing `<E*mu_en/rho>` in the _text file_. This case may be fixed by inserting `; nextfile` after `$3`.